# access parent movieclip class variable from child/inside movieclip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Maze Runner MovieClip has a "AS Linkage" class MazeRunner

MazeRunner class

```
public class MazeRunner extends MovieClip 
{

    public var _startCave       :String;

    public function MazeRunner():void
    {

    }
}
```

and movieclip (Maze Runner>mc_terrain) wants to access _startCave from "MazeRunner" class to be used in "mc_terrain" timeline.
can it be done?

i tried using var mr:MazeRunner = new MazeRunner(); - but it's an error cause i think you can't access your own class/movieclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Maze_Runner is a DisplayObjectContainer and mc_terrain is a DisplayObject attached to Mazerunner via addChild:

```
var mr:MazeRunner = new MazeRunner(); // you have to have an instance of MazeRunner to run it, anyway
var mt:Terrain = new Terrain();
mr.addChilld(mt);
```

then you can use

```
(mc_terrain.parent as MazeRunner)._startCave
```

to access it.

If they are not attached this way, then you need to reference the MazeRunner inside a mc_terrain (you need a new property for that):

```
var mr:MazeRunner = newMazeRunner;
mr.mc_terrain.maze_runner = mr;
// ...access:
trace(mc_terrain.maze_runner._startCave);
```

Lastly, if you always have only one active instance of MazeRunner, you can change its _startCave property to static:

```
public static var _startCave       :String;
```

This will allow you to modify and read it from any place using static reference:

```
MazeRunner._startCave = "1";
trace(MazeRunner._startCave);
```

But it is generally not recommended as it may lead to issues if MazeRunner happens to have several instances which need different _startCave's.

Comment: sorry for my earlier comments. one of your suggestions worked! but now when i use the following codes: 

""`var mr:MazeRunner = new MazeRunner();
mr.terrain.maze_runner = mr;
// ...access:
trace(terrain.maze_runner._startCave);`""

only "access to unidentified property terrain" occurs at

""`trace(terrain.maze_runner._startCave);`"" why is that?

Comment: undefined property terrain means that you're accessing it from a wrong context.
Use mr.terrain for example. It depends on where you call trace from. If you call trace in the main timeline, use mr.terrain. If calling from mr context, just terrain should work.

Comment: when i change `trace(terrain.maze_runner._startCave);` to `trace(mr.terrain.maze_runner._startCave);` flash pro freezes after running it. whenever i try using mr."anything" flash freezes.

Comment: What is MazeRunner class? Is it your class or are you using someone's code?

Comment: MazeRunner is a "AS Linkage" to Maze Runner MovieClip. it's my class with some code added from other codes.

Comment: It is hard to understand the cause of freeze. I can only suggest you take this MazeRunner class in a clean project and run it maximally simplified trying to get a basic acces to any of its property until you have avoided the freeze or understood the cause. After that slowly add other features one by one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70518/discussion-between-andrei-nikolaenko-and-jcr10).